# LINQ is Generating Extra IS NULL Condition in SQL Statement

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm writing some LINQ to fetch records based on an email, however, the generated SQL contains an additional `IS NULL` condition which doesn't need to be there because I am checking the parameter value for null in the code prior to adding the condition to the query.

My LINQ code is:

```
if (email != null)
{
    query = query.Where(r => r.Email == email);
}
```

The SQL condition generated from this is:

```
(([Extent1].[Email] = @p__linq__0) OR (([Extent1].[Email] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL)))
```

The

```
(([Extent1].[Email] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))
```

doesn't need to be there as far as I can see.

Is there any way to get LINQ to omit it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

They're there in case `email` is null.

You can prevent this by setting [UseDatabaseNullSemantics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.usedatabasenullsemantics(v=vs.113).aspx) to `true`

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether database null semantics are
>   exhibited when comparing two operands, both of which are potentially
>   nullable. The default value is false. For example (operand1 ==
>   operand2) will be translated as: (operand1 = operand2) if
>   UseDatabaseNullSemantics is true, respectively (((operand1 = operand2)
>   AND (NOT (operand1 IS NULL OR operand2 IS NULL))) OR ((operand1 IS
>   NULL) AND (operand2 IS NULL))) if UseDatabaseNullSemantics is false.

There are various ways to apply this.

If you only want to apply this to a single query you can do something like this:

```
using(TheContext dbContext = new TheContext()) {
    dbContext.Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true;

    ...

    if (email != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(r => r.Email == email);
    }
}
```

If you want to apply this to all queries:

```
public class TheContext : DbContext
{
    public TheContext()
    {
        this.Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true;
    }
}
```

You can also change the property to be `[Required]`:

```
public class Model {
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nicholas - is it possible to disable this on a per-query basis?

Comment: "If you only want to apply this to this query:" -- That modifies the *context*'s configuration, so clearly applies to all queries run on that context.

Comment: @hvd is that the case if you just set it before this query, while wrapping `new Context()` in a using statement?

Comment: @Nicholas Yes, if you only run a single query on that context, that context's configuration only applies to that single query. There is no indication in the question that a fresh context is or can be created for this query though.

Comment: In code-first, adding the [Required] attribute to the property sets the field to non-nullable which also removes this condition. I had a couple of fields that should have been explicitly set to non-nullable in this way.

Answer (score 0):

In C# `null == null` yields true
In ANSI SQL `null = null` yields unknown, which is neither true nor false

LINQ translates C# semantics to SQL, so for this expression:

```
r.Email == email
```

it will generate a query similar to the following:

```
WHERE t.Email = @email OR (t.Email IS NULL AND @email IS NULL)
```

which produces the following truth table¹:

```
Email | @email | Result
foo   | foo    | true
null  | null   | true
foo   | bar    | false
foo   | null   | unknown
null  | foo    | unknown
```

which is exactly what you would expect from C#². [This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/null-comparisons) explains EF null value handling in detail.

---

> Is there any way to get LINQ to omit it?

I would not worry about it as long as (i) the query produces expected result even for null (ii) the performance is not (significantly) affected.

---

¹ In SQL `unknown OR false` yields unknown
² For the purpose of filtering only true values are considered