# EF Core 2.2 query produces WHERE IS null for nullable column

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a table with three columns. Client Id is nullable.

```
public class ProductType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public long? ClientId { get; set; }
}
```

When I run the following code:

```
public async Task GetClientType(string productTypeName, long clientId)
        {
            var clientResult = await (from productType in context.ProductType
                                      where productType.Name == productTypeName
                                            && productType.ClientId == clientId
                                      select productType).FirstOrDefaultAsync();


            .......
        }
```

I dont get any results back although database contains results for this query.
I then checked the query that is produced by EF Core and I see that the following is produced:

```
SELECT TOP(1) [productType].[Id], [productType].[Name], [productType].[ClientId]
FROM [ProductType] AS [productType]
WHERE [productType].[ClientId] IS NULL AND (([productType].[Name] = 'test client') AND ([productType].[ClientId] = 1))
```

I can see that the problem is the `Where` clause. Why is this statement being produced?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen value in the query you mean?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen because it does not return any results where as it should as data exist for the specified parameters

Comment: I see now that `ClientId` is referenced twice in your SQL. You have in your LINQ query, `= clientId`, I assume `clientId` here is a variable. Can you tell me which type this variable has, and what the current value is?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen you mean SQL generated by EF Core

Comment: Yes, the one you posted in your question.

Comment: Edited the original post and added method signature. Value I pass for Client is 1 and 1 exists in the database

Comment: And there are no more attributes for `ProductType` or any of its members? That is exactly how it is declared?

Comment: No. Nothing more exists

Comment: Then I don't know, never seen this behavior before. I have one general SO-related tip though, make your question super-clear. You could do that here by writing in the last line an explanation of what you see in the WHERE clause that is wrong, and also by unwrapping the WHERE line in the code so that the second, good, reference to ClientId isn't hidden by having to scroll for it. By wrapping that line, and explaining that the problem is that both `ClientId is null` and `ClientId = 1` is added, the first one (likely) kills the result. This was what stumped me to begin with.

Comment: The question to "Why is ... WHERE ... IS NULL" added would most often be "You passed in NULL as the parameter". Now it is clear you're not doing that, and that two distinct comparisons for the column is added, one of them seemingly out of nowhere.

Comment: are you sure that `IS NULL` not `IS NOT NULL` ? that may come from `long clientId` parameter and  `long? ProductType.ClientId` .... also it is important which database are you using

Comment: Do you have multiple definitions for `ProductType` in your project (in different namespaces, obviously)?

Comment: @pantonis In your `DbContext` constructor, try setting the UseDatabaseNullSemantics to true and run your query: `this.Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true;`

Comment: I found the problem. A global query filter was added to the context which was causing the where clause. I changed it to ```from productType in context.ProductType.IgnoreQueryFilters()``` and now it works as expected without adding the ```WHERE [productType].[ClientId] IS NULL```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ is Generating Extra IS NULL Condition in SQL Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50444806/linq-is-generating-extra-is-null-condition-in-sql-statement)